# Why am I receiving a "type could not be found or is not registered as safe" error for my iframe web part?

Tags: iframe, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I am working on a farm solution in sharepoint 2013. I want to open a page in an  iframe that has been passed a URL as its src.

So I made a visual webpart with a .ascx file which looks like this:

```
<asp:HtmlIframe id="frm2"   runat="server" src="" height="600px" width="900"></asp:HtmlIframe>
```

And in the server side code (ascx.cs) I set the src property like this:

```
frm2.Src = "http://wwww.google.com";
```

However, I the web part generates the following error:

> Web Part Error: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type SharePointProject2.Employee.Employee, SharePointProject2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b6ac6e2971e56b29 could not be found or it is not registered as safe. Correlation ID: c41f8d9d-2f85-509f-fa04-e1d0062edc96.

On going through problem I found various solutions like this to add this to a web.config file.

```
<Assembly Location="MyAssembly.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache">
      <SafeControls>
        <SafeControl Assembly="MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3b7ec4bdc16ce8b2" Namespace="Myblog.WebParts" TypeName="*" />
      </SafeControls>
```

1. First Of All their is no web.config file in my sharepoint project
2. Whenever I open the project in empty farm solution no web.config file is there.
3. So I manually made a web.config file which is the xml file and add some code to it.

My application when running on Windows Server R2 is working well, and all the people can view it which are there in Active Directory, but when I stop the application then the same error comes in safe mode.

Please help me understand how to open a external application (to which I have a URL) in iframe using server side code on SharePoint.

What approach should I use, with the need to use server side code and in provider hosted server?

Thanks In Advance Guys

Basant Gera
​​

Comment: Is this SharePoint 2010 or SharePoint 2013? The deployment of custom user controls changed slightly between those versions.

Comment: I am working on SharePoint 2013.Than How can I use the User Control In SharePoint 2013.Like I frame ,Label  in client site code.It execute well when i deploy it but after that when i try to see it on other active directory account connected to the server it says the above error.I have also used safe control also in .spdata file.Stilll issue is not resolved.